# how to order map by vector value c++

Tags: c++

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> tmp_map = { { 1, [10,5,4] }, { 2, [5,5,1] },
        { 3, [2,4,3] }, { 4, [9,7,8] } };
```

I want to order this map by the 3rd value in vector value.
So the outcome will be like :

```
{ { 2, [5,5,1] },{ 3, [2,4,3] },{ 1, [10,5,4] },{ 4, [9,7,8] } }
```

Comment: [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) allows custom Compare functions.

Comment: sorry can you be more specific?

Comment: maps are sorted by their keys, that's how they work. So to sort the data in the way you want you are going to have to copy it to a different data structure, a vector of pairs for instance.

Comment: With a custom comparator you can sort anything by any criteria, subject to some caveats. You can even use a lambda in newer C++ versions. As john says, convert this to a vector, then sort it.

Comment: Or you could swap the key and the value around and use a custom comparator in your swapped map. Or if you want both orderings simultaneously you could use boosts [multiindex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)

Comment: I think it will be appropriate to convert it into vector and sort it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard approach . . .

- Copy map to vector
- Sort vector with custom comparator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::vector<int>> tmp_map = { { 1,{10,5,4} }, { 2,{5,5,1} },
        { 3,{2,4,3} }, { 4,{9,7,8} } };

    // For easier and shorter writing
    using DataType = std::pair<int, std::vector<int>>;

    // Create Vector with Elements from Map
    std::vector<DataType> data(tmp_map.begin(), tmp_map.end());

    // Sort data
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), [](const DataType& d1, const DataType& d2) { return d1.second[2] < d2.second[2]; });

    // show result
    for (const auto& [key, value] : data) {
        std::cout << key << "  -->  ";
        for (const int i : value) std::cout << i << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're `map` is already sorted by its key value so you cannot reorder it inplace. What you should do instead is copy it into a vector and then sort it using a custom operator like this:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::vector<int>> tmp_map = { { 1, {10,5,4} }, { 2, {5,5,1} },
        { 3, {2,4,3} }, { 4, {9,7,8} } };

    //! Copy the map
    using P = std::pair<int, std::vector<int>>;
    std::vector<P> copy(tmp_map.begin(), tmp_map.end());

    //! Sort it the way you want (here I'm sorting on based on the second element
    //! of the array.
    std::sort(copy.begin(), copy.end(), [](const P& a, const P& b)
    {
        return a.second[2] < b.second[2];
    });
}
```